# Dehalogenation of vicinial halides via Sodium Amide vs Sodium Ethoxide

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, regioselectivity

I noticed that vicinial dihalides can undergo elimination to create two alkenes or an alkyne. These are the following reactions I've seen.

[image: From Solomons & Fryhle Organic Chemistry 10th Edition Problem 13.16]

From Solomons & Fryhle 10th Edition Organic Chemistry Problem 13.16

[image: from https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Illinois_Springfield/UIS%3A_CHE_267_-Organic_Chemistry_I(Morsch)/Chapters/Chapter_08%3A_Alkyl_Halides_and_Elimination_Reactions/8.09%3A_E2_Reactions_and_Alkyne_Synthesis]
from [E2 reactions and Alkyne synthesis](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_Illinois_Springfield/UIS%3A_CHE_267_-_Organic_Chemistry_I_(Morsch)/Chapters/Chapter_08%3A_Alkyl_Halides_and_Elimination_Reactions/8.09%3A_E2_Reactions_and_Alkyne_Synthesis) on LibreTexts

Is it just the heat that makes a difference here? (i.e. could you get an alkyne to form with sodium ethoxide under cold conditions), or is it a combination of the difference in heat and reagent?

A [similar post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41888/why-does-treatment-of-a-geminal-dihalide-with-sodium-amide-lead-to-an-alkyne-and) about the dehalogenation of gem dihalides mentioned the relevance of heat (especially that reactions with sodamide typically lack it), so I'm fairly certain that heat does distinguish the two outcomes, but I'm not sure if there is something special about sodamide as well.

Comment: Write formulas with hydrogens and see if you get it then.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have fixed the question so that it actually makes sense.

Comment: Umm, I'm not so sure you got it. If you want to compare reaction with amide and etoxide, then first example isn't great, because you simply couldn't get the triple bond.

Comment: As far as the difference in reactions with these reagents in general, I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/101339/can-vicinal-dihalide-produce-conjugated-alkene-in-strong-base

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48347/what-is-the-major-product-in-the-reaction-of-2-3-dichlorobutane-with-sodium-amid

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/23966/why-can-syn-periplanar-e2-elimination-happen-in-molecules-like-vinyl-bromides-bu

Comment: Oh, whatever... Etoxide is simply not strong enough (at least in solution), amide is.

Comment: Judging by the references in comments, it seems possible the free electron pair in an amine adduct could influence the adjacent carbon, forming an aziridine intermediate.  Elimination would form the triple bond.  Ethoxide may not be able to do the same after it replaces one of the bromines.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I hope nothing I linked there says it. That's just elimination! Ethoxide eliminates to double bond, amide can react further, because it's a friggin' strong base.

Comment: @Mithoron and it's friggin' hot too!  That, and a bowl full o' nucleophiles strongly suggests an equilibrium somewhere.  Br- is literally swamped with sodium amide *and* ammonia.  I'm seeing a solvent effect and, perhaps not an aziridine closed ring, but the free nitrogen electron pair (as an intermediate) interacting with the adjacent hydrogen on the nearest carbon (4 membered complex and/or solvent effect).  I'm seeing, perhaps a concerted reaction leading to double elimination.  Just a thought.

Comment: The **intramolecular** concerted mechanism yields 2 ammonia and the triple bond.